# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Korean on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, translation, scope, specific-question

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Korean?
>
> - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
>     network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!
> - Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it    be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more
>     interested people.
> - Please share the page and invite others to like it in order to have more committers and probably a successful launch
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.
>
> Hint: I just want those bulleted paragraphs in Korean not more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you very much for asking on the meta site before posting. I do note that you have asked similar questions on other language sites, though, which IMO isn't really a suitable use of the meta system, as some of those sites have very clear policies on this.

Unfortunately, we are leaning towards 'pure' translation requests of any length being off topic on the main site -

[What is the policy for translation requests?](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-policy-for-translation-requests)

https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

However, as this relates to a request to help another SE community, my suggestion would be to ask in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41465/korean-language) if a member here interested in Remote Sensing and Photogrammetry would be interested in helping out at that Area51 site. Even then, [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/am-i-permitted-to-advertise-this-proposal-on-the-chat-section-of-other-stack-exc) may be relevant .

Comment: thanks for your advice about asking in the chat. I'll try :)

Comment: @sepideh As snailplane mentioned in [your question on Japanese SE](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/is-asking-to-translate-a-short-paragraph-from-english-to-japanese-on-topic-here), the chat room isn't intended as a bulk translation service. Also, you need to note that there is no native Korean speaker that frequents the chat room. I just wanted to let you know this so that you won't waste your time.