# Are questions on vocabulary off topic?

Tags: discussion

After a discussion with a native speaker, I realized that parts of the foot vary in terms of vocabulary and wondered what interesting aspects of the conversation might turn up in a question on the subject.

The comment seems to have been deleted, but I was emailed that someone commented asking if these words could not be found simply in a dictionary.

I'm not asking "should we avoid starting questions that say 'what is the Korean for the word cat?'"  I think it's clear that that would not be useful nor interesting.

Nevertheless I thought I would check meta and find out if my question on the foot were equally too simple and uninteresting and thus should be avoided.

Comment: I see there is some relation to this [meta discussion](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/should-we-change-our-off-topic-rules-to-allow-small-translations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to state the obvious first, [vocabulary](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is our second-most popular tag, so clearly some vocabulary questions are fine! However, [on-topic](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) currently asks users to avoid:

> - Simple general reference questions and character
>     recognition requests that can be answered by a resource such as a
>     dictionary (***although requests for help and clarification after
>     consulting a resource may be acceptable***)

(emphasis mine).

But it also says that the following questions **are** allowed:

> - Specific problems encountered when learning Korean appropriate usage    of language in real-life contexts
> - how to express an idea in idiomatic Korean
> - the meanings of Korean words or expressions where not clear from dictionary definitions

Taking all of those together, I'd summarise it as: If you're asking a question that *looks* like it could be answered just by using a dictionary, **it has to be clear what the particular 'angle' is** that makes the question more interesting than just  'what is the Korean for the word xxx?'.

For example -

- The fact that you noticed that that terms for parts of the foot vary (you mentioned this above, but I'm not sure it was stated in the actual question)
- wondering if there's some easy way to learn parts of the foot
- wondering if names for parts of the foot relate to names for parts of the hand

etc... any of those additional perspectives could elevate the question beyond a simple reference question.

The current answer to the question is good, partly because it has considered some angles that a dictionary wouldn't give. But perhaps it's true that the question as initially worded could have been clearer at presenting those possible angles - sometimes asking a question too straightforwardly can leave other users guessing a bit at what's really being asked.

Comment: thx, let me try to clean that up over the next few days...i suddenly got busy with family/work/etc.  a very good answer - again, thx!

Comment: @WEBjuju thanks to you too for all your recent work adding content to the site !