# Is asking for lyrics transcription on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

> I just found this song on my computer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKlkaeZ8Fog&pbjreload=10. I suspect it might be Korean except for the spoken part which seemed like Chinese. The comments suggest a title: 사랑 할 께, where "sarang hal" is the relative clause present form of "sarang hada", "to love", and kke is some particle, would that mean "in order to love" (I see kke means "for")? Or is that misspelt? In any case, am I right in my suspicion, i.e. is that actually Korean?
>   If so, could someone transcribe the lyrics for me?
>   
>   (Also, would this question have been on-topic on the site?)
>   PS The suggested title yields via Google search http://testicanzoni.mtv.it/testi-%EC%B1%84%EC%97%B0_289361/testo-%EB%84%90-%EC%82%AC%EB%9E%91%ED%95%A0%EA%BB%98-5488513, which doesn't seem to match the beginning of the song in the video, which I hear as 널크다로와솔 or the likes.
>   (No -l in the last syllable).

Posted this in chat around 6h+ ago. Since the room is inactive since then, I decided I would ask:

> Are questions as the above one, that is, questions requesting lyrics transcription and/or the identification of a song as being in Korean, on-topic here?

Comment: Chat is a bit quiet, but I have replied now - perhaps the thing is to @-tag one or two of the more familiar names in there so that they get a notification.

Comment: This isn't significantly different to https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/261

Comment: translation requests are fine, but "here's my homework/something I heard the other day, translate it for me" type of questions might not be received properly. In any case, since text translations are allowed here, I think song lyrics translations should be allowed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've replied in chat about the particular song: seems to be [this one](https://littleariel13.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/%EC%82%AC%EB%9E%91%ED%95%A0%EA%B2%8C-i-will-love-you-only-you-ost-the-one-han-rom-eng/).

I don't think we've discussed this question before, so I can't point to a 'site policy'. My personal opinion would be:

- Requesting a whole transcription or translation of a song is probably not a great type of question for here, as it's a lot of work, most of which doesn't go into discussing the language (which is what this site is about)
- requesting identification of a song is fine in chat; probably also off-topic for the main site.
- if you want to translate or transcribe a song and are able to do most of it yourself but are stuck on a few lines, I think asking someone to 'fill in the gaps' would be OK on the main site. That gives the answerer a better opportunity to discuss the language in those particular lines.