# Could help with translating larger passages be on-topic, and if so, what's the best way to ask and answer such questions?

Tags: discussion, translation

We've had a couple of questions recently that seem to be asking for help with a number of difficult words in larger passages:

[Terminology related to Social Thoughts and Korean Society: 위정척사, 공맹사상, 가묘, 종묘, 위패](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/terminology-related-to-social-thoughts-and-korean-society-%EC%9C%84%EC%A0%95%EC%B2%99%EC%82%AC-%EA%B3%B5%EB%A7%B9%EC%82%AC%EC%83%81-%EA%B0%80%EB%AC%98-%EC%A2%85%EB%AC%98-%EC%9C%84)

[Help regarding terminology on Korean history: 정화오례신의, 주자가례, 진사시, 재지지주, 강남농법, 등](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/help-regarding-terminology-on-korean-history-%EC%A0%95%ED%99%94%EC%98%A4%EB%A1%80%EC%8B%A0%EC%9D%98-%EC%A3%BC%EC%9E%90%EA%B0%80%EB%A1%80-%EC%A7%84%EC%82%AC%EC%8B%9C-%EC%9E%AC%EC%A7%80%EC%A7%80%EC%A3%BC-%EA%B0%95%EB%82%A8%EB%86%8D%EB%B2%95-%EB%93%B1)

Can we help with these kind of questions, and what's the best way to do so?

Comment: For the questioner, the minimum requirement for this type of question should be to either (1) provide a larger context showing the passage the word appears in or (2) provide 한자 if it appears in the text, since it looks like many (if not most) of these terms are 한자어. It can often be very difficult to determine the meaning/definition of 1-4 syllable 한자어 only rendered in 한글 without either the context or 한자.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think it could be fine to ask about a number of points of difficulty in a larger passage, as long as we follow what we've already said about small translations in https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

> ... context, and any specific difficulties encountered, [should be] made as clear as possible
>
> Please make your question as clear as possible, with any necessary context, examples and references, and any research already done.

To me, this would mean:

- The passage to be translated should be put into the question, to provide sufficient context.
- Ideally, any attempt so far to translate the passage would also be put in the question.
- The number of points of difficulty is reasonable, such that a decent answer can be sensibly short.
- If any particular words are being asked about that can be found in an online dictionary, the difficulty with existing translations is made clear.

I think this would be in the spirit of 'fill in the gaps' as suggested for [Is asking for lyrics transcription on-topic?](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/is-asking-for-lyrics-transcription-on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

My thought about things that are risen in learning Korean

(1) Need of China's character :

In fact, classes of China's character harass many Korean students of
middle or high school periods.

Even though he do not complete the course, then big problem may not
occur.

나의 적(敵)은 게으름이다

니 적(籍) 적은 무엇이니 ?

Here 적 can be interpreted as two meanings. First is enemy and
second is job.

So frequently official document contains China's character, but in
generally we know the meaning through context.

(2) Historical terminology :

In fact, almost all Korean people do not know the word 위정척사

Even though he has heard that word once, almost all people do not
 care it. And even though we do not know these words, we can enjoy
 historical drama or movie.

I believe that if you know a lot of things on Korean culture, and
   if you want to know China's history of low level, then the
   checking is helpful.